# .htaccess rewrite to another domain on the same server without url change

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a web application that has "pretty urls". The `.htaccess` file there looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)(/)?([a-z0-9]+)?$ /home/user/domains/domain1.com/public_html/sites/index.php?site=$1&page=$3 [QSA]
```

So when I enter `domain1.com/site/page` it actually shows me `domain1.com/index.php?site=site&page=page`. This works fine.

#### BUT

I have another domain, let's say `domain2.com`. I have it in the same account in the DirectAdmin. When I enter the ftp account and go to `domains/` I see there both `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`.

I want to force `domain2.co.il` to show `domain1.com/index.php?site=domain2`

I placed the same `.htaccess` file (with a minor change of the `site` parameter) in the `public_html` of `domain2.com`. The result is 404 error.

So the question is: How to make it work the way I want?

---

I also read the following posts, but I can't seem to find use out of them. Maybe I just don't understand how:

- [2 domains 1 host -> domain url rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231648/2-domains-1-host-domain-url-rewrite)
- [How can I redirect to a different domain without changing the URL in the address bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987343/how-can-i-redirect-to-a-different-domain-without-changing-the-url-in-the-address)
- http://www.directadmin.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-1528.html

Comment: Do you have access to the `.conf` files, of apache? or is the `mod_proxy` module enabled? or can you enable `mod_proxy`? else not possible.

Comment: I think I can gain access to both of those features. But how does this help me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your folder structure looks like

```
/domains
    /domain1.com
    /domain2.com
```

You can do this using the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)? ../domain1.com/index.php?site=domain2&q=$1 [L]
```

There's a good chance you'll have to use PHP's `chdir()` function to get it operating in the proper directory, which you can do by passing `chdir()` the PHP magic constant `__DIR__`.

Comment: Both `RewriteRule ^(.*)? ../domain1.com/public_html/sites/index.php?site=elizur&q=$1 [L]`, and `RewriteRule ^(.*)? ../../domain1.com/public_html/sites/index.php?site=elizur&q=$1 [L]` (I think the `public_html` causes it to be 2 levels up) result in a `400` error (`Bad Request. Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.`)

Comment: That's rather odd. The rule above works fine on my server. It may have to do with the server's configuration in that case. It's especially odd since you already have FollowSymLinks turned on.

Comment: Can you think of any configuration that might be blocking this?

Comment: Not immediately. If anything, I might expect a Too Many Redirects error, so this is rather confusing. I'll see if I can't trip the error on my own server when I have time.